# How to generate an Activation Key (or Serial Key)

Tags: php, serialization

My problem is this : 
I have a user id : 0001
And Expiration code : 2015-10-10 12:00

What I need is to encrypt the two value so that I can have some like :
TRE-3DR-SER-WER-67J-AX3 (something like this), and also can be decrypted to its original values.

What I did was to jumble the two value, remove spaces and dashes and create a letter or number equivalent to a single character.

My problem is I want the generated kay to be more secure and harder to decode and if possible shorter string.

Comment: By doing that you're allowing decryption techniques to take place. You should generate a random key, and assign it to a userid an expiration table but leave them seperate

Comment: So, you want your own, custom and safe encryption ? I would rather use existing solutions... :)

Comment: Meeting your requirements and being hard to decode are two mutually exclusive objectives.

Answer (score 3):

You should keep the activation key seperate, and irrelevant to expiry date and user ID. It's literally creating a method to decrypt your own keys. Instead; have your table similar to the below.

```
+----------------------------------------+
|   UserID    |    Key    |    Expiry    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Than you can generate the ID:

```
<?php
function sernum()
{
    $template   = 'XX99-XX99-99XX-99XX-XXXX-99XX';
    $k = strlen($template);
    $sernum = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$k; $i++)
    {
        switch($template[$i])
        {
            case 'X': $sernum .= chr(rand(65,90)); break;
            case '9': $sernum .= rand(0,9); break;
            case '-': $sernum .= '-';  break; 
        }
    }
    return $sernum;
}


// try it, lets generate 4 serial numbers
echo '<pre>';

for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) echo sernum(), '<br/>';

echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

> WS41-IZ91-55XO-23WA-WVZS-20VK
>
> SJ42-CV50-79DA-55UV-TERR-28IJ
>
> LY80-CN84-69LV-73EW-ZZEU-09AI
>
> IS86-RG15-39CG-38HK-XLUG-86FO

Then check to see if the generated key is in use (1/1,000,000 chance~)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Yes I know the practice is bad but still i want to do it.
I also know that the date expiry should be separated and I can just check via mysql if the user is expired.

What i want to know is how can I make the encryption harder to decode.

Comment: The only way would be to make the serial key longer in length, you can edit the template in the `sernum()` function to make it longer or shorter, contain more numbers or contain more letters. Decoding it would reveal nothing anyway. Billion dollar companies are still asking this question and failing at it so don't try to hard.

Comment: @Zanderwar It's not the billion dollar companies who are failing, it's the coders those cheap bastards hire ;-) not to mention how hackers get more and more savvy.

Comment: Not to mention younger as well :P

Answer (score -1):

Encoding:

```
 $user = "0001"; //Solution only works if this value is always 4 characters.
 $datetime = "2015-10-10 12:00";

 $reps = array("-", " ", ":");
 $unencoded = $user . str_replace($reps, "", $datetime);
 //gives: 001201510101200

 $encoded = strtoupper(base64_encode($unencoded)); 

 //This will always be 20 characters long
 //Result: MDAXMJA5OTK5OTAXMJAW

 $finalCode = substr($encoded, 0, 5) . "-"
              .substr($encoded, 4, 5) . "-"
              .substr($encoded, 9, 5) . "-"
              .substr($encoded, 14, 5) . "-"

 //result: MDAXM-JA5OT-K5OTA-XMJAW
```

Decode:

```
 $input = "MDAXM-JA5OT-K5OTA-XMJAW";

 $encoded = str_replace("-", "", $input );
 $decoded = base64_decode($encoded);

 $year = substr($decoded, 4, 4);
 $month = substr($decoded, 8, 2);
 $day = substr($decoded, 10, 2);
 $hour = substr($decoded, 12, 2);
 $min = substr($decoded, 14, 2);

 $userid = substr($decoded, 0, 4);
 $date = new DateTime($year . "-". $month . "-" .$day. " ".$hour.":".$min);
```

Note: I would not recommend doing this, it is very insecure. I would follow the advice of some of the other answers and keep your code random and seperate to the user ID and date/time.